# How to add close 'X' in ng-bootstrap popover

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, popover, ng-bootstrap

I am a newbie to angular 5, I am trying to add 'x' in top right of popover, on clicking 'x', the popover should be closed. How do I achieve this? Below is my code. Is there any property in popover to display 'x' close icon. Here I am trying to use ng-bootstrap popover.

```
  <div>
    <a *ngIf="conditionA" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled">
      {{ authorName }}
    </a>
    <a *ngIf="!conditionB" href="#" (click)="showPopover(accountId)" placement="top"
      popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" [ngbPopover]="popContent" #p="ngbPopover" (document:click)="closeAccount(p, $event)">{{ Display_popover }}</a>
  </div>

<ng-template #popContent>
        <app-account-detail></app-account-detail>
      </ng-template>
```

Comment: I found it, I need to include additional span tag in ng-template, but on clicking close 'x' it says " Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined"                                                                     
                                                                                                                             
  `<ng-template #popContent>
        <span class="popover-close" aria-hidden="true" (click)="p.close()">×</span>
        <app-beneficiaries-detail></app-beneficiaries-detail>
      </ng-template>`

Comment: can you add stackblitz

Comment: have you defined the close() function in your component ts file?

Answer (score 4):

Must work (and no, it's not necesary defining a "close" function)

```
<!--in template we write "p.close()"-->
<ng-template #popContent>
    Hello, !
    <button (click)="p.close()">click</button>
</ng-template>

<!--look that the button that lanch the pop over has a "#p=ngbPopover" -->
<button type="button" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [autoClose]="false" 
      triggers="manual" #p="ngbPopover" (click)="p.open()" >
  Click me to open a popover
</button>
```

***Update*** in *ngFor (I don't know if work)
If we have the popOver in a *ngFor, You can try a work around

```
<section *ngFor="let account of accounts"> 
   <ng-template #popContent>
       Hello
       <button (click)="close(p)">click</button>
   </ng-template> 
   <button type="button" [ngbPopover]="popContent" 
         [autoClose]="false" triggers="manual" 
        #p="ngbPopover" (click)="open(p)" >Click me</button>  
</section>

In the .ts
  close(pop:any)
  {
    pop.close()
  }
  open(pop:any)
  {
    pop.open()
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-girkhz)

Comment: thanks @Eliseo but it still didn't work. My bad, I should have been more clear in my question. The popover is placed inside *ngFor and it doesn't recognize p.close()                                                                                  `<section *ngFor="let account of accounts">                                                        <ng-template #popContent>Hello<button (click)="p.close()">click</button></ng-template>
<button type="button" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [autoClose]="false"      triggers="manual" #p="ngbPopover" (click)="p.open()" >Click me</button> </section>`

Comment: @Nicolas, I don't know if work using a function and pass as parameter "p" as I show in the updated answer

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, I tried that but didn't work. The issue here is, when it is looping, it is not able to recognize the "p" reference from within `<ng-template></ng-template>`. However if the above pop-over code is not placed inside the loop, then everything works fine.